# Docker push to private registry issues

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Here is what I have setup:

Docker daemon running as insecure registry as below:

```
docker -d --iptables=true --insecure-registry 1.2.3.4:5000
```

Now, when I try to push to that registry from a remote system it is giving me different errors.

Error 1:

```
docker push 1.2.3.4:5000/test
EOF error: 
FATA[0002] Error: Invalid registry endpoint 1.2.3.4:5000/v1: Get 1.2.3.4:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
```

Error 2: After getting error 2, I added the ip to the /etc/hosts on the docker host. If I try "docker push docker:5000/test" it tries to use https and fails with Error 1 and if I try "docker push docker/test", it is asking me for a username and password. Is this expected ??

```
Error:
The push refers to a repository [docker/test] (len: 1)
Sending image list

Please login prior to push:
Username: docker
Password:
Email: docker@internet.com

FATA[0011] Error response from daemon: Registration: "Forbidden username"
```

If it needs authentication, where can I find my username and password. Also can I start the docker registry without authentication ??

Comment: I figured it out. I was running the command from the docker registry rather than the deamon and so the issues. After adding insecure-registry in the docker host, restarting docker and then running docker push works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have your private registry running you need to retag the image you want to upload. Assuming the command docker images returns a image called jason/test you use the docker tag command to copy it with a new name:

```
docker tag jason/test <server.name>:<port>/<image name>
```

Assuming that your internal docker registry is accessible via the dns name myregistry.mycompany.local and it running on the default port of 5000 the command would look like:

```
docker tag jason/test myregistry.mycompany.local:5000/test
```

The docker images command will now show:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
myregistry.mycompany.local:5000/test   latest              c776f089e3cf        6 days ago          707.3 MB
jason/test               latest              c776f089e3cf        6 days ago          707.3 MB
```

Now you can run docker push myregistry.mycompany.local:5000/test to push the image to your internal registry.

Comment: Hey guys, I figured it out. I was running the command from the docker registry rather than the deamon and so the issues. After adding insecure-registry in the docker host, restarting docker and then running docker push works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Running the Docker daemon with the argument `--insecure-registry` does not start an insecure registry, it just allows it to connect to one.

The command `docker push 1.2.3.4:5000/test` was trying to connect to a registry at `1.2.3.4:5000`, but it doesn't exist, so it errors out.

The command `docker push docker/test` tries to push to the official Docker Hub, which requires you to have set up an account, hence asking you for a username and password.

Have a look at the [Github repository for the registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) for details on how to run your own registry.

Comment: I found Digital Ocean's instructions on how to make a private repository really helpful. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks Adrian & @ryan1234. Thanks for your suggestions. As stated above, after adding insecure-registry in the docker host, restarting docker and then running docker push works. Also Ryan, I will take a look at the digital ocean tutorial to see how can I improve docker setup. One question I had was on how to upgrade docker registry with a new docker version ? Thanks.

Comment: To upgrade the registry just pull the image again and start a new container.